# Sur la signification du nom « pif » en Pif et Hercule

Tags: noms-propres

*Pif* signifie soit un gros nez soit (avoir) du flair, de la perspicacité.

Je me demande si le nom de ce personnage d'animation célébré a du rapport avec l'un des sens de ce mot devenu nom propre ; s'il y a du lien, c'est-à-dire, entre « pif » et Pif.

Comment: There is no 's' to "Hercule" in French. I would edit but title has to be 15 characters long and with the 's' it's *exactly* 15 characters long ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je pense que le créateur de [Pif le chien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pif_le_chien), [José Cabrero Arnal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Cabrero_Arnal), a choisi ce nom en référence au flair particulièrement affuté des chiens.

On trouve des référence du même type avec [Skippy le kangourou](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skippy_le_kangourou) ou [Flipper le dauphin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flipper_le_dauphin) où on accole une caractéristique évidente avec un animal emblématique.